# Does Allure support Cucumber JVM 6.0.0?

Tags: java, cucumber, allure

I have a project that uses Java 8 and Cucumber 6.0.0. I've tried to follow https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm, however, there is no `io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber6-jvm` JAR available. Previous versions of `io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber????-jvm` don't work with Cucumber 6.0.0.

Is there a way how to integrate Allure with Cucumber 6.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my research and knowledge, Allure comes with different dependencies for each version of cucumber like allure-cucumber2-jvm, allure-cucumber3-jvm, allure-cucumber4-jvm, allure-cucumber5-jvm.

As of now you won't see any dependency for cucumber6. But you will get it soon. It's been only 3 months of releasing cucumber 6

Answer (score 0):

yes, in the pom.xml download the following allure dependency:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-cucumber6-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber6-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

then in surefire plugin config to use it:

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.link.issue.pattern</name>
                        <value>https://example.org/issue/{}</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.link.tms.pattern</name>
                        <value>https://example.org/tms/{}</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    -Dcucumber.plugin="io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

you also need to update aspectj dependency and define it as a property.
tried today and it was working.